# regex to match identifiers without double _

Tags: regular-expression

I want a regex to match identifiers consisting of letters, digits and `_`, without double underscores. My current attempt:

```
^(?!_)(?!.*?_$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

Example:

```
Abdfsdfsdf__ 
1B2345_
v1__23456
__23456789b
12345-6789
123456789
1_fsdfdfsdf
v_fsdfsdf_fsdfd
v_123
v__123
v134234_fsdfsd
123456
a1b2c3d4e5
```

Matched:

```
v1__23456
v_fsdfsdf_fsdfd
v_123
v__123
v134234_fsdfsd
a1b2c3d4e5
```

How can I remove the rows `v1__23456` and `v__123` from the matches?

Comment: You want print all lines have two underscores, or you want print all lines have only one? Your match doesn't contain `v1_23456`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!_)           # don't start with _
(?!.*?_$)        # don't end with _
[a-zA-Z]         # the first character must be a letter
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$   # after that digits and underscores are ok
```

You've expressed in two different ways that the first character must not be `_`, but nothing here says anything about `__` in the middle.

Using negative lookahead, it is simple to express “one or more alphanumeric characters or `_`, don't start with `_` or a digit, don't end with `_`, and don't allow `__` anywhwere”:

```
^(?![0-9_]|.*__.*_$|)[0-9A-Z_a-z]+$
```

Without negative lookahead (e.g. in awk or `grep -E`), you can split the pieces:

```
^[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*(_[0-9A-Za-z]+)*$
```

Start with a letter, then zero or more alphanumerics, then you can have underscores but each one must be followed by one or more alphanumerics.

Comment: thx. and thanks for understand what i want to express.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do it:

```
perl -nle 'print if /(_)*.*\1/' pattern.txt
```

Ouput:

```
1B2345_
12345-6789
123456789
1_fsdfdfsdf
v_123
v134234_fsdfsd
123456
a1b2c3d4e5
```

The regex `/(_)*.*\1/` will match all line have two or more underscore `_`. Just negate the condition to print lines that don't match.

Comment: i think i shown the wrong meaning.   I test this in the RegexBuddy to check my regex could match the username or not

Comment: Finally, you want to match line has double underscores `__` or line contains double underscores, i.e `__` or `_<some char>_`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to find lines that DO NOT contain two consecutive underscores? Unless I'm missing something, this should work:

```
    grep -v '__'
```

or to remove lines that contain any number of consecutive underscores:

```
    grep -v '__*'
```

or to remove lines that contain multiple adjacent underscores, but keep lines that contain only single underscores:

```
    grep -v '___*'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -E '^(_?[A-Za-z0-9])*[A-Za-z](_?[A-Za-z0-9])*$' example.txt
1_fsdfdfsdf
v_fsdfsdf_fsdfd
v_123
v134234_fsdfsd
a1b2c3d4e5
```